# Create fragment and put it to TabHost?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm adding tabs to **FragmentTabHost - mTabHost** in my FragmentActivity:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("visit").setIndicator("Visit"), VisitTabFragment.class, bundle);
```

but I need a reference to my TabFragment. I found a partial solution, that I can set my

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

        if (fragment instanceof VisitTabFragment)
            visitTabFragment = (VisitTabFragment) fragment;
...
}
```

but it works only when I click on my tab. I tried also:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

but it gaves me NullPointerException (probably it doesn't exists yet).

Is there a way to **create fragment first** and then add it to tabhost?

Comment: Can you explain your ultimate goal? What do you need the Fragment reference for?

Comment: If you want to create fragment first, you should **initialize** before adding

Comment: @M.Mariscal How can I add initialized fragment to tabHost?

Comment: mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById (android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator("T1"),
            T1Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("t2").setIndicator("T2"),
            T2Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("t3").setIndicator("T3"),
            T3Fragment.class, null); Hope it helps!

Comment: @M.Mariscal But where you store reference to T1Fragment, T2Fragment and T3Fragment? That's my goal :) I want to create fragment and later add it to tab.

Comment: public class T1Fragment extends Fragment  {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.t1_view, container, false);
        return v;
    }
} It's a class extending from Fragment, Tabhost extends from FragmentActivity Hope it helps my friend!

Comment: @M.Mariscal I've done that. I want just something like that:
mTabHost.addTab(visitTabFragment), where visitTabFragment is instance of VisitTabFragment which I initialized before. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your tabhost before adding tabs to it:

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabContent);
```

For reference can use ***sinleton pattern***:

```
public class VisitTabFragment extends Fragment {
      private static VisitTabFragment uniqInstance;

      private VisitTabFragment() {
      }

      public static VisitTabFragment getInstance() {
        if (uniqInstance == null) {
          uniqInstance = new VisitTabFragment();
        }
        return uniqInstance;
      }
      .........
}
```

When you want to access your fragment should call:

```
VisitTabFragment.getInstance();
```

In your case call:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("visit").setIndicator("Visit"), VisitTabFragment.getInstance().getClass(), bundle);
```

Comment: mTabHost.addTab has 3 arguments: TabSpec, **Class**, Bundle. I can't put instance here.

Comment: I was missed that point. I have edited my answer. Let me know if now works for you.